# find the particular node which fit three criteria neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I would like to find the name node which trade with three fruits only.
I tried to use the following code in neo4j.

```
match (s:good)-[r:TRADES]-(n:Name)-[:TRADES]-(p:good)
WHERE (s.good = 'Apple' or s.good='Orange') and p.stock ='Grapes'
return s,n,p
```

where it returns the query as below.
[image]
However, I just want the following. Just the one who trade Grapes, Orange and Apple only.
[image]

I don't know which part of the cypher is incorrect. thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a knowledge base article on [match intersection](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/performing-match-intersection/), what you're trying to do here, however your other restriction is that these are the only 3 connected nodes, so we have some additional work to do.

Using the first approach in the article, we just have to add an additional predicate to ensure the degree of :TRADES relationships equals the size of the collection:

```
WITH ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Grapes'] as names
MATCH (g:good)<-[:TRADES]-(n:Name)
WHERE g.good in names AND size((n)-[:TRADES]->()) = size(names)
WITH n, size(names) as inputCnt, count(DISTINCT g) as cnt
WHERE cnt = inputCnt
RETURN n
```

Comment: Hi @InverseFalcon I would like to know if I have another query with more than 5 fruits. What I need to need change is from three elements to five elements on WITH ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Grapes'] as names ?

Comment: The type of query provided doesn't use any hard-coded numbers for expected values, if you read through it you should notice it uses the number of elements in your input, so whether it's 3 or 5 or 5000 it should work the same.

Comment: However, if I want to query if any name node which have connected with three or more fruit nodes. I think this query won't be able to provide the name nodes?

Comment: Then just change up the last WHERE clause with the numbers you want: `WHERE cnt >= 3`

Comment: Hi @InverseFalcon Thank you for your help, yet it cannot resolve the question. I have raised another question below. If you have time please take a look. Thank you so much
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53629951/find-cluster-in-neo4j