# Find cluster in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi I have a neo4j database, similar to below.

```
CREATE
  (:Person {name: 'Ryan'})-[:TRADES]->(fish:Product {name: 'Fish'}),
  (ken:Person {name: 'Ken'})-[:TRADES]->(fish),
  (mary:Person {name: 'Mary'})-[:TRADES]->(fish),
  (john:Person {name: 'John'})-[:TRADES]->(fish),
  (ken)-[:TRADES]->(book:Product {name: 'Book'}),
  (ken)-[:TRADES]->(plum:Product {name: 'Plum'}),
  (ken)-[:TRADES]->(cabbage:Product {name: 'Cabbage'}),
  (ken)-[:TRADES]->(tomato:Product {name: 'Tomato'}),
  (ken)-[:TRADES]->(pineapple:Product {name: 'Pineapple'}),
  (mary)-[:TRADES]->(Pizza:Product {name: 'Pizza'}),
  (mary)-[:TRADES]->(book),
  (mary)-[:TRADES]->(plum),
  (mary)-[:TRADES]->(cabbage),
  (mary)-[:TRADES]->(tomato),
  (ian:Person {name: 'Ian'})-[:TRADES]->(fish),
  (ian)-[:TRADES]->(pork:Product {name: 'Pork'}),
  (john)-[:TRADES]->(pork),
  (ian)-[:TRADES]->(oil:Product {name: 'Oil'}),
  (ian)-[:TRADES]->(pasta:Product {name: 'Pasta'}),
  (ian)-[:TRADES]->(rice:Product {name: 'Rice'}),
  (ian)-[:TRADES]->(milk:Product {name: 'Milk'}),
  (ian)-[:TRADES]->(orange:Product {name: 'Orange'}),
  (john)-[:TRADES]->(oil),
  (john)-[:TRADES]->(rice),
  (john)-[:TRADES]->(pasta),
  (john)-[:TRADES]->(orange),
  (john)-[:TRADES]->(milk),
  (peter:Person {name: 'Peter'})-[:TRADES]->(rice),
  (peter)-[:TRADES]->(pasta),
  (peter)-[:TRADES]->(orange),
  (peter)-[:TRADES]->(oil),
  (peter)-[:TRADES]->(milk),
  (peter)-[:TRADES]->(apple:Product {name: 'Apple'}),
  (ian)-[:TRADES]->(apple);
```

I would like to query the names who buy 5 or more same items. (In this case, it's Peter, John and Ian as group1, Ken and Mary as Group2). In for all possible items

[image]

[EDITED]
Added desire output

My Desire output is similar to below
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. Answer for initial question

### 1.1 Creating your graph

For the ease of possible further answers and solutions I note my graph creating statement:

```
CREATE
  (:Person {name: 'Ryan'})-[:TRADES]->(fish:Product {name: 'Fish'}),
  (:Person {name: 'Ken'})-[:TRADES]->(fish),
  (:Person {name: 'Mary'})-[:TRADES]->(fish),
  (john:Person {name: 'John'})-[:TRADES]->(fish),
  (ian:Person {name: 'Ian'})-[:TRADES]->(fish),
  (ian)-[:TRADES]->(pork:Product {name: 'Pork'}),
  (john)-[:TRADES]->(pork),
  (ian)-[:TRADES]->(oil:Product {name: 'Oil'}),
  (ian)-[:TRADES]->(pasta:Product {name: 'Pasta'}),
  (ian)-[:TRADES]->(rice:Product {name: 'Rice'}),
  (ian)-[:TRADES]->(milk:Product {name: 'Milk'}),
  (ian)-[:TRADES]->(orange:Product {name: 'Orange'}),
  (john)-[:TRADES]->(oil),
  (john)-[:TRADES]->(rice),
  (john)-[:TRADES]->(pasta),
  (john)-[:TRADES]->(orange),
  (john)-[:TRADES]->(milk),
  (peter:Person {name: 'Peter'})-[:TRADES]->(rice),
  (peter)-[:TRADES]->(pasta),
  (peter)-[:TRADES]->(orange),
  (peter)-[:TRADES]->(oil),
  (peter)-[:TRADES]->(milk),
  (peter)-[:TRADES]->(apple:Product {name: 'Apple'}),
  (ian)-[:TRADES]->(apple);
```

[image: Graph]

### 1.2 Solution

```
MATCH (person:Person)-[:TRADES]->(product:Product)
WITH person.name AS personName, count(product) AS amount
WHERE amount >=5
RETURN personName, amount;
```

- first line: defining the matching pattern
- second line: count products per person
- third line: filter for brought products amount
- fourth line: render the result

### 1.3 Result

```
╒════════════╤════════╕
│"personName"│"amount"│
╞════════════╪════════╡
│"John"      │7       │
├────────────┼────────┤
│"Ian"       │8       │
├────────────┼────────┤
│"Peter"     │6       │
└────────────┴────────┘
```

---

## 2. Answer for new question and requirements

### 2.1 Solution

```
MATCH path=(sourcePerson:Person)-[:TRADES]->(product:Product)<-[:TRADES]-(targetPerson:Person)
WITH sourcePerson, targetPerson, count(path) AS pathAmount, collect(product.name) AS products
  WHERE pathAmount >= 5 AND id(sourcePerson) > id(targetPerson)
RETURN DISTINCT products, collect(sourcePerson.name) AS sourcePersons, collect(targetPerson.name) AS targetPersons;
```

### 2.2 Result

```
╒════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤═══════════════╤═══════════════╕
│"products"                                          │"sourcePersons"│"targetPersons"│
╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════╪═══════════════╡
│["Tomato","Cabbage","Plum","Book","Fish"]           │["Mary"]       │["Ken"]        │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┤
│["Milk","Orange","Pasta","Rice","Oil"]              │["Peter"]      │["John"]       │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┤
│["Milk","Orange","Pasta","Rice","Oil","Pork","Fish"]│["Ian"]        │["John"]       │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┤
│["Apple","Orange","Milk","Rice","Pasta","Oil"]      │["Peter"]      │["Ian"]        │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────┘
```

### 2.3 Note

The result shown differs a little from your expectation, since for the relations `Ian->Apple<-Peter`, `John->Pork<-Ian` and `John->Fish<-Ian` your requirement "persons who bought more than four products" is met also and thus it creates a separate cluster.

---

## 3. Alternative

If the fine granular clustering does not meet your requirements, you can also drop the "bought >4 products" requirement. In this case the solution would look like this:

### 3.1 Solution

```
CALL algo.louvain.stream('', '', {})
YIELD nodeId, community
WITH algo.getNodeById(nodeId) AS node, community
  ORDER BY community
WITH community, collect(node) AS nodes
WITH
  community,
  [x IN nodes WHERE ('Person' IN labels(x)) | x.name] AS persons,
  [x IN nodes WHERE ('Product' IN labels(x)) | x.name] AS products
RETURN community, persons, products;
```

- line 1: call the [Neo4j Graph Algorithms](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/3.5/) procedure [Louvain algorithm](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/louvain/)
- line 2: define result variables
- line 3: retrieve values from the result stream
- line 4: order the community values
- line 8: filter the resulting nodes for label `Person`
- line 9: filter the resulting nodes for label `Product`
- line 10: render the output

### 3.2 Result

```
╒═══════════╤══════════════════════╤═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"community"│"persons"             │"products"                                                   │
╞═══════════╪══════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│0          │["Ryan","Ken","Mary"] │["Fish","Book","Plum","Cabbage","Tomato","Pineapple","Pizza"]│
├───────────┼──────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│1          │["John","Ian","Peter"]│["Pork","Oil","Pasta","Rice","Milk","Orange","Apple"]        │
└───────────┴──────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

If you prefer the node itself instead of the names, just remove both `| x.name` parts in the last `WITH` clause.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer, however, if I want to find the intersection for people who bought the any 5 same item. Is it possible to query the people and item node? (In this case, it is Ian, John and Peter, and the items are Rice, Orange, Pasta, Milk and Oil?)

Comment: HI @ThirstForKnowledge I have updated my question. Thanks again

Comment: I’ve extended my answer by two different solutions (chapter two and three).

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, I have two follow up question.
1.) Is it possible to show nodes in Solution 2?
2.) When I put Solution 3 into my actual dataset, some of the rows of product list is less than 5. Is it possible to limit the length of product list at least 5 products?

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Yes. If you remove the `.name` part in line two, as well as the two occurrences in the last line, you will get nodes.

Comment: Unfortunately, with the chosen approach of alternative 3, I do not see any possibilities to limit the product list to 5 and above. That is the drawback of this alternative.
On the other side: Take a look at the [Cypher projection chapter](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/louvain/#_cypher_projection_5) of the Louvain algorithm. Defining your custom input query with an product list of 5 and more could help you.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will read about it. If I only want to find the product.name as ["Milk","Orange","Pasta","Rice","Oil"], I just need to need product name in the WHERE statement like pathAmount >= 5 AND id(sourcePerson) > id(targetPerson) AND products= 'Milk' or products= 'Orange' or products='Pasta' or products= 'Rice' or products= 'Oil' or products = ["Milk","Orange","Pasta","Rice","Oil"]

However, it doesn't work